# For $f$ to be integrable over some interval, must it be defined over that entire interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For $f$ to be integrable on some interval, must it be defined over that entire interval?

I ask this question because 
$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
 0 & x\neq 1 \\
 1 & x=1 
 \end{cases}
 $
is integral on $[0,2]$ but is not continuous on that interval.  So what happens if we leave $f$ undefined at $x=1$?  I'm talking about darboux/riemann integral.

Comment: For Riemann integral there is no problem as long as there is only a finite number of such points, as one can see that the value on a finite number of points does not change the integrability nor the value of the integral. However there is a problem for a countable number of points.

Comment: It is easy to prove that a function on $[a,b]$ which is continuous except on a finite number of points is Riemann integrable. Making the function  undefined in some points cause so much technicalities/troubles.

Comment: As another example, integrals such as $\int_{-1}^1 dx/\sqrt{|x|}$ are perfectly well defined.

Comment: You always assume the function is defined everywhere in the interval and bounded there. That is the basic starting assumption in the theory.